# When you can't see the trees for the forest - how can you ask a question that's not 'too broad'

Tags: discussion

I've just deleted [my question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/224456/separation-of-concerns-in-a-complex-reporting-application) that had been put on hold as 'too broad.'

I don't think that it shouldn't have been put on hold.  While the comments I received helped me solve my problem, I recognize that the question would have added little of value to the site as a whole.

In this case, several commenters appeared to believe the question encompassed several valid questions that I should have broken out and asked individually.  If only I could have picked them out.

Is there is a way to ask an acceptable question when you know that the crux of the problem is that you can't see the trees for the forest?

Comment: you seem to have sufficient reputation to use [chat] - this is probably most appropriate place to "preview" and discuss what you are going to ask

Comment: I forgot that a 'programmers chat' was attached to this - thanks @gnat - what's the best way to 'preview' a question with a lot of detail on chat - put it up on a gist and then include the link in the chat message?

Comment: I just tested - whole text of your question can be copied and pasted as-is into single chat message (chat collapses it into few lines and gives readers an option to expand). This is a bit too straightforward, but probably makes a simplest starting point / stuff to discuss

Comment: No disrespect, but I think you really overtook the plumbing with that question.  Sometimes the simplest thing that works is best.  The simplest thing does have the virtue of being relatively inexpensive to rip out and replace if you realize later that you need something (slightly) more complicated.

Comment: No disrespect in return, but "overtook the plumbing" ?  I'm not sure quite what that means.  If you mean that I was over-engineering, perhaps.  I was starting to get overwhelmed in my own code, trying to manage the interplay between explicit options and options required based on a particular report ...  The options mentioned in the question are all options supported in the current codebase, and I was faced with adding five more reports, so it wasn't a YAGNI situation.